# How to Design the Following Data Structure in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, global-variables

I have a list, `L1<A>`, of about 60 to 120 objects, `A`, that themselves contain a list `L2<D>` of objects, `D`.

The `L2<D>`s are identical for all `A`.

The user can upload new `D`s, and every time the program has to go through all of L1 and add add the new `D` to each `L2`. Obviously, I would rather have a master `L2` that can just be updated once and have every `A` refer to that list, but I don't want to make some kind of global variable `L2`.

If I make a single instance of `L2`, do I just have to pass `L2` to every `A` in `L1`, or can I get each `A` to refer to the single `L2` without using a global variable?

Comment: Passing around a shared instance is not the same as a global variable, and seems like a perfectly appropriate solution.

Comment: Sounds like you should pass the one L2 to every A as a *constructor* argument, but I can't be sure since you've omitted any information about what these things actually mean.  The next time you ask a question like this, don't try to turn it into something so generic -- not all similar questions have the same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static` variable is what you are looking for.

```
public class A {
    private static final List<D> l2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addD(D d) {
        l2.add(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `l2` is static, `addD()` should also be. But it's usually better to avoid global state.